# Drop null rows with dtype object from a DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Oper    ST  result
T2  9:24:09 NaN
T3  9:25:10 Fail
T4  9:25:36 Pass
T5  9:25:36 NaN
```

I want to drop the NaN rows from the 'result' column. All columns are dtype object:

```
df.dtypes

Oper    object
ST      object
result  object
```

If I print the values and dytpes to a list they appear in this format:

```
rlist = df['result'].tolist()
for r in rlist:    
    print(r,type(r))

-> nan <class 'float'>
```

I tried these things unsuccessfully:

dropna:

```
df.dropna(subset=['result'])
```

filtering:

```
df = df[df['result'] != 'nan']
```

I also tried to find a way to convert the object to a string and then filter but could not find a way to do that either.

Comment: try this: `df[df.result.notnull()]`

Comment: Thanks MaxU, but that also did not work.

Comment: What is `df['RAT']`?  Your sample data doesn't have such a column.

Comment: what about: `df[df['RAT'] != 'NaN']`?

Comment: @root, sorry that was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: @MaxU, df[df.result.notnull()] does work if I assign the result back to the dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dropna` does not work in-place: you have to assign the result to the dataframe itself or it will be lost:

```
 df = df.dropna(subset=['result'])
```